# Trying to identify a martial arts movie, I thought it was called "The Golden Arrow"

Tags: identify-this-movie, martial-arts

Hi I'm trying to identify a martial arts movie, I thought it was called "The Golden Arrow".
I saw it sometime in the early 90s

I can't remember all that much, but the scene I remember is when the main character has his master firing arrows at him, while he is blindfolded.  He dodges/deflects them all but then catches "The Golden arrow"  His master rushes over asking how he knows to catch that one and tell him his training is complete.

I think there may be a part of the movie where he starts to glow golden but I'm a bit more hazy on that part!

Comment: Can you remember if it was an american movie?

Comment: I don't remember, sorry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the movie you are talking about is "[The Last Dragon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089461/combined)" - 1985 martial arts musical film. The following is an excerpt from a website describing parts of the movie and fits in with your description (not sure if I am allowed to link to random sites here, I can add them if I am)

> His master fires arrows at him, and he deftly smacks them in half.
>   Very useful, if he's ever attacked by the Sioux nation. He mixes up
>   the routine a little by catching the last arrow, which just happens to
>   have blue feathers instead of black. How did he know that, him master
>   asks of him? Was it because it was the third arrow, and his master
>   just works in patterns? No, he just knew, he explained. Well that
>   tears it. When you can guess the color of arrow feathers, you have
>   officially moved beyond receiving colored belts (or dragon patches, in
>   this case). His training is complete. One thing is still bugging ol'
>   Leroy: when he masters... whatever martial art he's working on, he's
>   supposed to give off some kind of glow to signify his mastery, and yet
>   he merely glistens with sweat.