# Western with extremely sweat-lathered horses

Tags: identify-this-movie, western

I recently watched a western that showed some (feasibly only one) extremely sweat-lathered horses. They'd been ridden hard, but I honestly can't remember if it was in the context of a horse-race, outrunning Indians, or whatever. I'm kinda stuck because I've already tried to reference it in an answer over at english.se [What does "Whip into a lather" mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58880/whip-into-a-lather/58886#58886)

Sorry - I know that's not much to go on. But the lather was pretty extreme!

Comment: -1 I can't understand why anyone would up-vote this question?  "I'm trying to identify a movie with very sweaty horses"!!  I don't even know why they were sweating! Similarly for the up-votes on the answer!

Comment: @AidanO - [Same people that upvote questions like this I guess?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/trying-to-identify-a-martial-arts-movie-i-thought-it-was-called-the-golden-arr)

Comment: @AidanO [Just proves that this site is community driven](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/283/why-are-answers-with-minimal-information-getting-up-voted)  There are almost 900 users each with their own (hopefully) unique opinion :)

Comment: @AidanO: Not my call really, but I would say in the movie it's hardly "sweaty" horses - they look like they've had cans of shaving foam emptied all over them! I thought it was quite striking, and it's possible others may remember the scene but not recall much else about what the movie was about or what it was called. If someone asked on writers.se ["I read this book where the narrator wrote of how eating a small tea-cake brought back vivid memories of childhood"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involuntary_memory), would that not be a good question?

Comment: @Martin, I wouldn't have expected that question to get many up-votes either to be honest...

Comment: @FumbleFingers now if you'd have said that in your question, I wouldn't have downvoted it!  I tried to remove my down vote but it's too late, so will upvote the comment, which i do think adds plenty to the question.  Sorry if I came across like a crank.

Comment: @AidanO: I'm not sure which bit of what I said in my comment would have made a difference, but please feel free to edit the question to reflect it - or anything else you think might "improve" it. The more I think about it, the more it seems to me questions seeking to identify movies by citing some "iconic scene" may actually become quite useful as part of a "knowledge database". It's usually easy to identify iconic lines of dialogue just through Google, but getting the right search terms for visual elements is a bit trickier - movies.se could end up being quite good for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ooops! - I found the answer myself! It's [Bite the Bullet (1975)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072705/), starring Gene Hackman, Candice Bergen and James Coburn. Not as good a movie as I'd have hoped from that line-up, in all honesty.

The movie centres on a 700-mile "endurance horse race". I think one of the central themes is basically that it's "the American way" to *win at all costs*. Per [the answer on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58880/whip-into-a-lather/58886#58886) about the meaning of *Whip into a lather*, the horses may not actually be as distressed as one might think, but it certainly makes a striking image.

Comment: [It's perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)  Just as long as it is a good question to begin with :)

Comment: @TylerShads: I do think the "lathered horses" scene, which is very near the end of the movie, is quite memorable. Given it's quite an old movie, someone else may have seen it a long time ago, and only be able to remember that aspect. So unless question and/or answer get many downvotes I guess I'll assume it *is* a good question. Even if I did happen to find the answer myself!

Comment: Makes me think of Buster Keaton's infamous 'horse sweat' scene in 'A Funny Thing Happened on the Way to the Forum'.

Comment: @Nobby: I haven't seen it - I was never a fan of silent movies, and don't know anything Keaton did after the "talkies" came in. But he must have been on his last legs in that one, since he died in 66 when it was released.

Comment: His was a small role, and he was indeed an old man, but the gag never fails to make me laugh. I won't spoil it for you - it's a good film to watch late at night when you are drunk :)

Comment: @Nobby: I *am* intrigued, so I probably will (don't tell anyone else, but stuff like that I normally nick via torrents! :)